# Efficient way to fetch amount from signed integer until zero in C++?

Tags: c++

What is an efficient way in C++ to decrement and return a limited portion of an signed long integer until zero. The portion size is defined in an unsigned integer?

The use is in a busy interrupt routine of a small 16MHz processor.

I was experimenting with something like this:

```
#define limit(amt,lim) ((amt)<(-lim)?(-lim):((amt)>(lim)?(lim):(amt)))

long pile = 3452;
int maxportion = 100;


while (pile!=0)
{

    int portion;
    portion = limit(pile, maxportion);
    pile -= portion;

    //Code to apply portion here..

}
```

The while loop is just for demonstration. For the implementation i hope to find a "subtract and return portion" that feels ok to execute once every interrupt regardless of pile is zero or not.

Comment: Your existing approach seems OK although I would use an inline function instead of the macro; to avoid multiple evaluation and signed/unsigned problem

Comment: you might want to divide into two cases for positive,negative that you determine before the loop (to avoid repeating the positive/negative test each iteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @M.M writes, you might consider changing the macro to an inline function. The only thing I might add is that, if you know the distribution of cases, you might speed up things using something like [`likely` and `unlikely`](http://blog.man7.org/2012/10/how-much-do-builtinexpect-likely-and.html). For example, here is code optimized for the case where *|amt| < |lim|*.

```
inline long limit(long amt,long lim)
{
    if(unlikely(amt < -lim))
        return -lim;
    else 
    {   
        if(unlikely(amt > lim))
            return lim;
        return amt;
      }
}
```

As usual with performance, YMMV. You should profile and see.

Comment: In my sample code i used a while loop, but the actual use of the "decrement pile by portion" is in an interrupt routine that handle one portion or what is left of the ever changing pile in each interrupt. For each new visit/(loop) the pile may have changed to any size and sign.